# Run jquery function only one time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var num ="1";
    document.getElementById("numid").setAttribute("value", num);
    document.forms["form"].submit();
});
```

When i load this page, it will keep submit and submit again.
Is there any way can let it just run one time ?

Comment: Your form submit is reloading the page. That's why the code keep on submitting.

Comment: once the document is ready the flow comes inside this block and get submit the page. So page will get refresh and load again. so this block is getting looped again and again.

Comment: What's the purpose of submitting the form on page load?

Comment: What do you want your page to do after submitting?

Comment: as others have said, submitting something causes a page reload which means you are stuck in a loop

Comment: @Quannt after  submitting it will show a number in a text field

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var num ="1";
    document.getElementById("numid").setAttribute("value", num);

    var form = document.forms["form"];

    form.on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    form.submit();
});
```

Not sure why you need to submit the form on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery Instead of dom API

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var num ="1";
    $('#numid').attr('value',num);
    $('#form').submit();
});
```

also use prevent default

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var num ="1";
    var isSubmit = false;

    document.getElementById("numid").setAttribute("value", num);

   if(!isSubmit){
    document.forms["form"].submit(function() { 
        isSubmit = true;
     });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you perform  `document.forms["form"].submit();` the page is reloaded. So I guess that you are using the wrong approach to the problem. Maybe you could do an ajax request and replace some part of the webpage that should change after this `document.getElementById("numid").setAttribute("value", num);`

Try something similar

```
$.ajax({

     type: "POST",
     url: 'http://something.com',
     data: "id=" + num , 
     success: function(data) {
           $('#someDiv').html(data);
     }
   });
```